# 'myname'@'%' can access to mysql server remotely but not with 'myname'@'123.456.489.%'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working on accessing to mysql server remotely. My home pc to pc at the office.

I can access with `'myname'@'%'`.

[image]

but I can't with `'myname'@'123.456.489.%'`.
`'123.456.489.012'`(redacted) is the IP address(IPv4) of my home pc.

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

I don't know why.

I tried to connect by setting user's host IP address to the remote client IP address without wildcard like '123.456.489.012(redacted)'. but even in this setting, I can't connect..

Comment: Check your real IP by open site https://ifconfig.co

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I checked my ipv6. May I ask how to set this address to the setting: 'Limit to the host matching'?

Answer (score 0):

`123.456.489.012` is not a valid IPv4. SO you cannot login by `123.456.489.%`.

For ipv6 use right format.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'user'@'2001:db8:0:f101::%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

and in remote site (for example 2001:db8:0:f101::2)

> shell> mysql -h 2001:db8:0:f101::1 -u user -ppass

Read [Connecting Using IPv6 Non local Host Addresses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html) for more information.

Comment: `123.456.489.012` I wrote in the OP is a dummy data, though? Should it be always in the IPv6?

Comment: No, if you use ipv6 for communication it must be ipv6. Else use ipv4. However % will cover ipv4 and ipv6. Using `'myname'@'123.156.189.%'` is a right format.

Comment: I see. then, I still don't know why 'myname'@'123.156.189.%' remote user can't access.. thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Anytime! Check that if you can connect with your real IP? use `'myname'@'123.156.189.5'` if your IP is 123.156.189.5.

Comment: I can't connect with my real IP, either.

Comment: So your problem is you IP not % or anything else. Can you give a `ip a` in linux or `ipconfig` in windows to find what is your real IP in remote host.

Comment: I checked my global IP address [here](https://www.luft.co.jp/cgi/en/ipcheck.php). and I have used this address. It should be correct address.

Comment: I mean, the IP address I set on user setting on the mysql server should be correct.

Comment: If you are in a network and use gateway it is not correct! Please check your local IP with commands I wrote before.

Comment: sorry i don't get it. so, use global IP address of my local pc to set user's host on mysql server is not correct?

Comment: most probably YES! if you are in a network (mysql server and remote client) you need local IP. If your server is on internet and you have access to it through internet it must be work with public address.

Comment: My home pc should be out of the network. My pc is home and the sql server is in remote office. I try to access through internet, so use of public address is ok, right?

Comment: Maybe you use a VPN for secure access. Check mysql logs to find real address. search for something like access denied.